# RFC 3339 date formatters - why is output date shifted by one day?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, rfc3339

We have received an issue in our existing iOS application developed using Objective-c.

Issue : The output date is shifting by one day back, only for PST time zone.

We have written below code for converting the date to short format.

```
-(NSString *)getDisplayDateFormat:(NSString *)dateString
{
    NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale;
    NSDateFormatter *inputformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    enUSPOSIXLocale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
    [inputformatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
    inputformatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
    [inputformatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssSSSZZZZ"];
    NSDate *date= [inputformatter dateFromString:dateString];
    NSDateFormatter *OutPutformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [OutPutformatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSString *dispalyDateString = [OutPutformatter stringFromDate:date];
    return dispalyDateString;
}
```

Input dateString = 2017-01-16T00:00:00-06:00

UTC Format : date = 2017-01-16 06:00:00 +0000

OutPut dateString = 2017-01-15

Kindly help us to fix the issue.

Comment: It's not wrong. What you are seeing is expected. And it is not just with PST (US West coast). It will show Jan 15 for any device with a timezone offset of greater than -6 (further west).

Comment: 2017-01-16T00:00:00-06:00 (e.g. midnight the morning of January 16st in Chicago), was 10pm on January 15th in Los Angeles. So your output makes sense. The question is what your broader objective is. Are you saying that you don't care what time something happens, only what day it was there? Then you probably shouldn't be including the time portion on your date strings at all. Stepping back, you should edit your question to describe the broader design objective and we can advise how to address it.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I am getting the date "2017-01-16T00:00:00-06:00"  from the server,  need to convert to  2017-01-16. Kindly Suggest.

Comment: If the date string doesn't reflect a moment in time, but rather just reflects a date, then you really should change the web service to return only the date. As it is, you should just get the first 10 characters, and the run that through your formatter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture the string representation of the date portion of a datetime string, irrespective of whether the local time zone used was different from your own, the easiest approach is to ignore all of the time and timezone information and just grab the date portion. In its simplest form, you could do:

```
- (NSString *)getDisplayDateFormat:(NSString *)dateString {
    return [dateString substringToIndex:10];
}
```

Or, if you really intended to convert it to the device's locale (in case the user isn't using a Gregorian calendar), then you would do:

```
- (NSString *)getDisplayDateFormat:(NSString *)dateString {
    NSDateFormatter *inputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
    [inputFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
    [inputFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSDate *date = [inputFormatter dateFromString:[dateString substringToIndex:10]];
    NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    return [outputFormatter stringFromDate:date];
}
```

Then, again, if you were trying to convert to the user's calendar, you presumably wouldn't use `yyyy-MM-dd` format, but rather you'd use some user-friendly `dateStyle`.

Answer (score -1):

Does anybody really know what time it is?  Try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *d = @"2017-01-16T00:00:00-06:00";

    NSArray *abbrevs = @[@"UTC", @"EDT", @"PST", @"HST", @"JST"];

    NSArray *names = @[@"UTC", @"America/New York", @"America/Los Angeles", @"Pacific/Honolulu", @"Asia/Japan"];

    for (int n = 0; n < abbrevs.count; n++) {

        NSString *na = abbrevs[n];
        NSString *nm = names[n];
        NSString *r = [self getDisplayDateFormat:d inTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:na]];

        NSLog(@"Time is %@ in %@ (%@)", r, nm, na );

    }
}

-(NSString *)getDisplayDateFormat:(NSString *)dateString inTimeZone:(NSTimeZone*)tz
{
    NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale;
    NSDateFormatter *inputformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    enUSPOSIXLocale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
    [inputformatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
    inputformatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
    [inputformatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssSSSZZZZ"];
    NSDate *date= [inputformatter dateFromString:dateString];
    NSDateFormatter *OutPutformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    //[OutPutformatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    // show the time also, for clarity 
    [OutPutformatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    // This is important! You must set the TimeZone for the output string - otherwise you get the local / device timezone
    OutPutformatter.timeZone = tz;
    NSString *dispalyDateString = [OutPutformatter stringFromDate:date];
    return dispalyDateString;
}
```

Comment: So, I'm relatively new to posting here on SO... curious why someone would down-vote this answer?

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but it was probably down-voted because this doesn't solve the OPs question. He has a some ISO8601 string and he wants to know what the date component was. He does not want to see the date in his local time zone. That's the problem with his original code, which you've simply reproduced here.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Rob. I was trying to convey to the OP that the actual *date* and how the date is *presented*, are two independent things. Perhaps if I had explained it in plain language, rather than providing demonstrative code, would have been a better approach.